# Could someone tell me what this stone might be

Tags: geology

It is 9 1/2 inches by 3 1/2 inches and weighs about 5 lbs. it was at this house in Florida when we bought it. It has a white 1/4 inch crust and the interior color looks somewhat topaz. [image]

Comment: It looks like a large flint nodule. Flint nodules occur in limestone, especially chalk limestone. Flint is a very common mineral, and therefore has no value unless it has been fashioned into  a tool  by ancient hominids. Chemically it is silicon dioxide, similar to quartz.. Voids in the limestone became filled by silicon-laden micro-currents which precipitated their  silicon dioxide content when passing through one of these voids. Flint occasionally contains small fossils

Comment: @MichaelWalsby why didn't you add this as an answer?

Comment: Because rock ID questions are usually  put on hold. I'm surprised this one hasn't been, but I expect it soon will  be.

Answer (score 2):

Most likely some form of chalcedony, not knowing where you found it, I'd call it flint, a form of chert.